# THIS APP CAN'T OPEN! App can't open while file explorer is running with administrator privileges. Restart file explorer normally and try again

Tags: vb.net, windows, selenium-webdriver

Running on win8.1

Whenever I want to open a windows store app via my winappdriver (selenium) in vb.net I'm getting following error:

> THIS APP CAN'T OPEN! "AppName" can't open while file explorer is
>   running with administrator privileges. Restart file explorer normally
>   and try again.

First searches around the internet suggest to restart explorer, this didn't bring any solution.

Running the windows application troubleshoot app also didn't solve this issue.

I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: You could try **throwing it out the window**... *it may help*? (jk)...

Comment: Are you compiling this project as an admin? If so you need to remove from doing that. Windows Store apps inherit administrative access tokens of the Explorer process that launch it. If Explorer is indeed running as an elevated process, this will violate the sandboxed environment provided by the AppContainer integrity level. Also on another note, there's an update to `winappdriver` that will remove building the project as an administrator: **https://github.com/imsardine/winappdriver/tree/master/src** did you try this?

Comment: I'm local admin on my pc, but I'm not starting the visual studio with adminstrator rights.I'm using the latest version as provided in the github link you've written in your comment. I've been trying with other apps as well, but they all throw the same message...